# Speak Form component is not working

Tags: speak, mvc-forms

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 to build a Speak application where I'm creating a form to add/edit items from the master database, so when I add a Form component and looking into the console of chrome browser it is showing error 'Uncaught TypeError: speak.component is not a function' from the Form.js file.

```
(function(speak) {
   speak.component(["jquery", "bootstrap"], function() {....
```

Comment: Please share some more details to help people understand the problem you are facing, may be some screen shots and more detail around the exception.